# How to get the entire document HTML including HTML inside iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want the content script to send the entire HTML to the background script after the page is fully loaded.

In the content script `document.documentElement.innerHTML;` returns the document HTML but not including the HTML inside `<iframe/>` elements.

Is there is a way to get the whole HTML of a page including the HTML inside `<iframe/>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to find the iFrame node and then use the contentDocument to get it's children to access the html.

Your answer: `iFrameNode.contentDocument.children[0]`.

`iFrameNode.contentDocument.children` will give you all the children of iFrame document but it will only have 1 that is html.

`iFrameNode.contentDocument.children[0]` should do the trick.